# C# equivalent to VB 6.0 code

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

```
Option Explicit  
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long    

Function TimerCreate() As Boolean

    If g_CTimer Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    ' Create the timer
    g_CTimer.TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, g_CTimer.Interval, AddressOf TimerProc)
    If g_CTimer.TimerID Then
        TimerCreate = True
    Else
        TimerCreate = False
        g_CTimer.TimerID = 0
     End If   
End Function  

Sub TimerProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long)
    On Error Resume Next

    If g_CTimer Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    g_CTimer.ThatTime
End Sub
```

Comment: You really need to ask a question. Is there something in particular you're having trouble with? Seems like a few minutes' study would get you about 95% there with a conversion. Then you could ask a *specific* question about whatever you're having trouble with.

Comment: i am having trouble while writing below line in C# with correct parameters and data type:   `g_CTimer.TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, g_CTimer.Interval, AddressOf TimerProc)`

Comment: You don't need any of that in C# because in .Net there are several `Timer` and the like classes that already do whatever you're doing here. What I mean is that a `VB6 -> C#` migration is not just translating the code. You need a full rewrite using .Net classes and OOP philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

For a timer, you probably want:

```
System.Threading.Timer myTimer =
    new System.Threading.Timer(TimerProc, null, g_CTimer.Interval, g_CTimer.Interval);
```

See [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).

If you really need to use the multimedia timers (I would not recommend it), I'd suggest you read up on [Windows Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check pinvoke.net for managed prototypes. For example, [SetTimer](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.settimer).